# Can't parse JSON after sending it via Ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js, koa

**Client side**

After applying `JSON.stringy` to an object it is sent like this to a node-server (as POST-request):

```
{"id":"topFolder","parentPath":null,"name":"newProject","is":"root","children":[]}
```

I'm sending the request on the client via Polymer's iron-ajax-element:

    `<iron-ajax
     id="ajaxSave"
     method="POST"
     url="/save"
     handle-as="json"
     on-response="doit"
   </iron-ajax>`

It is sent with this function:

```
save: function() {
  var v = JSON.stringify(this.data);
  this.$.ajaxSave.body = v;
  this.$.ajaxSave.generateRequest();
}
```

**Server side**

Then I try to `JSON.parse` the request's body on the Koa-server (using [Koa-Body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-body) as the body parser):

```
router.post('/save', body, function*(){
  let data = JSON.parse(this.request.body);
  this.body = "all ok";
})
```

I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` and the raw body looks like this:

```
{ '{"id":"topFolder","parentPath":null,"name":"new Project","is":"root","children":': [ '' ] }
```

**Why does the received body look different and how can I fix it?**

Edit: This is a full curl-command of the request:

> curl 'http://localhost:3000/save' -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46ZXZvbGE=' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/' -H 'Cookie: ajs_anonymous_id=%22e43155da-6541-45de-af9f-046ff5ac7b3c%22; currentUserId=34;  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data '{"id":"topFolder","open":false,"parentPath":null,"name":"new Project","children":[]}' --compressed

Comment: The error is in `"children":': [ '' ] `

Comment: Yes I can see as much but why is this happening?

Comment: edit your post with a detailed explanation of what do you do in order to have that you call **Json stringified** because that isn't json.

Comment: When you see `Unexpected token o`, this is almost always due to your JSON not being valid. The clue is the `o` - this usually comes from trying to run `JSON.parse` on `[Object object]`.

Comment: Can you show the POST parameters in full

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to test for JSON validity, as you can see there is a trailing apostrophe before the second curly open bracket

Comment: The POST data is converted to string and used as a key of the JSON object with single quotes notation which is incorrect instead of double quotes, which makes the JSON invalid.

Also you probably didn't want the JSON to be used by the server as a string. There should be something wrong with the decoding server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is already an object.

`JSON.parse()` is used to convert a string containing JSON notation into a Javascript object.

For example, try: `this.request.body["id"]` to get one of properties.

Comment: `this.request.body['id']` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `content-type` was set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
It has to be `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Usually body is not a string, so try to explicitly turn it into one.

```
body.toString()
```

If it doesn't help...
In some transport libraries you have to read body prior to use it by calling body.read(). Read operation can be async..

With q-io it looks like

```
request(someURL)
.then( function(res) {
  return res.body.read() 
})
.then( function (body){
  obj = JSON.parse(body.toString()
})
```